# Connect esp32 to hc-06 via BluetoothSerial. HOW?

Tags: arduino, esp32

Environment: Arduino IDE 
How could an ESP32 unit be associated with an HC-06 via Blueooth? 
I would like ESP32 to send data on BT to HC-06 using "BluetoothSerial.h".

Comment: It looks like you've identified how you want to connect. What have you tried? What hasn't worked with it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I tried this code running on Arduino + HC-06

https://github.com/VidiLAB-com/Arduino/blob/master/Arduino_Autic/Arduino_Autic.ino

And it works fine with the smartphone app connected to Bluetooth device called HC-06, and PIN 1234.

I would like to make an ESP32 Bluetooth controller for it. I tried the official code for Bluetooth classic:
https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/BluetoothSerial/examples/SerialToSerialBTM/SerialToSerialBTM.ino

Of course, I changed the variables:

```
String MACadd = "20:16:04:11:65:21";

uint8_t address[6]  = {0x20, 0x16, 0x04, 0x11, 0x65, 0x21};

String name = "HC-06";

char *pin = "1234";
```

& try to lower the Serial connection

```
Serial.begin(9600);
```

But that didn't help!